# I can't convert to double in C# using visual studio 2019

Tags: c#

I need help with using Convert.ToDouble. I am struggling to convert to double in C# and visual studio gives an exception. Do I need to install extensions?

this is all the code

```
using System;

namespace VariablesAndDataTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Variables dclarations amd types
            string name;
            int age;
            double salary;
            char gender;
            bool working;

            //Prompt users for Input
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
            age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter your salary: ");
            salary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // the exception is thrown here
            Console.Write("Enter your gender (M/F): ");
            gender = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Are you working (true/false): ");
            working =Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());

            //Print to Screen
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Your age is: {0}", age);
            Console.WriteLine($"Your salary is: {0}" + salary); // when  I write a double it gives and error and the console stops responding.
            Console.WriteLine("Your gender is: " + gender);
            Console.WriteLine("You are Employed: " + working);
        }
    }
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: I am new to programming

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Have you tried both '.' and ',' as decimal separators? Sounds like a 'current culture' thing

Comment: Money is best handled with `decimal` rather than `double`. Once you get it working (it may be a decimal point versus comma thing, what is you *locale*), consider using `Xxx.TryParse` rather than `Convert.ToXxx`. You can expect users to mess up data entry - it's hardly an *exceptional* event.

Comment: What is the value you are trying to to convert into double?

Comment: this is the exception: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: I tried using ',' and it responded. Thak You

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C# @Mickey

It could be that you've used the string interpolation($) wrongly

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine($"Your salary is: {salary}");
```

It would be quite helpful if you shared the exception you got though.

Comment: I tried that line and used ',' instead of '.' and it worked. Thank You